# What is the equivalent of setting values in a tensor with slices for PyTorch in LibTorch?

Tags: c++, tensor, libtorch

How can I do the equivalent of using matrices to index and store values in one matrix from another from Python but in Libtorch.

I'm trying to use an indexed matrix to slice another matrix in order to store values in it from yet *another* matrix.
This is a mouthful to English, so I have the working code and results in Python below. My failed attempt to recreate in Libtorch is below this.

The Python

```
cholesky = torch.zeros(8, 8, 8);
cholesky_vector = torch.rand(8, 36);
trl = torch.tril_indices(8, 8, 0);

cholesky[:, trl[0], trl[1]] = cholesky_vector

cholesky
```

It returns this matrix. Which puts the values exactly where I want them.

```
tensor([[[0.3111, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5975, 0.9703, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.6811, 0.4677, 0.7590, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0010, 0.8861, 0.8692, 0.3827, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.9845, 0.5214, 0.4913, 0.3317, 0.3694, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.4845, 0.9741, 0.9637, 0.2215, 0.6441, 0.4667, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5859, 0.2318, 0.1462, 0.4146, 0.4956, 0.0593, 0.2274, 0.0000],
         [0.1511, 0.9338, 0.1538, 0.1413, 0.6825, 0.8603, 0.3877, 0.6649]],

        [[0.3933, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.1842, 0.7173, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5992, 0.2769, 0.4918, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.8385, 0.5362, 0.7575, 0.2624, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.7518, 0.8498, 0.3258, 0.7684, 0.9668, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.6219, 0.1827, 0.3053, 0.6481, 0.4354, 0.3589, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5498, 0.2406, 0.4254, 0.1268, 0.3228, 0.7060, 0.1305, 0.0000],
         [0.5638, 0.2914, 0.6694, 0.5602, 0.2192, 0.9243, 0.6700, 0.5900]],

        [[0.3275, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0900, 0.9910, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.4400, 0.4655, 0.7230, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.4918, 0.1729, 0.4175, 0.1364, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.7576, 0.6224, 0.2054, 0.4986, 0.9193, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.9263, 0.3134, 0.1165, 0.4859, 0.1304, 0.4994, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.2482, 0.0410, 0.2839, 0.2058, 0.6699, 0.4444, 0.9273, 0.0000],
         [0.7618, 0.7198, 0.7269, 0.8574, 0.1796, 0.2194, 0.9194, 0.0787]],

        [[0.6033, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.9135, 0.7830, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3832, 0.9798, 0.7576, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.9165, 0.7926, 0.7782, 0.8400, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.4857, 0.5566, 0.2132, 0.5453, 0.7487, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.4757, 0.4697, 0.6746, 0.9064, 0.1400, 0.5734, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3156, 0.5101, 0.1733, 0.7964, 0.0968, 0.4890, 0.0794, 0.0000],
         [0.8430, 0.9914, 0.4553, 0.8600, 0.8010, 0.6438, 0.1823, 0.5365]],

        [[0.9651, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5155, 0.4745, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.5051, 0.7673, 0.3066, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0987, 0.0922, 0.5434, 0.8127, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.4180, 0.7377, 0.0269, 0.4656, 0.0229, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3197, 0.0206, 0.3944, 0.1476, 0.0851, 0.5571, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.2551, 0.2104, 0.4587, 0.6939, 0.5979, 0.2294, 0.1625, 0.0000],
         [0.7122, 0.8181, 0.0716, 0.7310, 0.4320, 0.4559, 0.1816, 0.6207]],

        [[0.1193, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.8168, 0.2408, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.1558, 0.6047, 0.0323, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.8517, 0.3109, 0.5395, 0.9577, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.7701, 0.0454, 0.2172, 0.9752, 0.8875, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0760, 0.3473, 0.0685, 0.1755, 0.4378, 0.0720, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3233, 0.8671, 0.6564, 0.1952, 0.8837, 0.8912, 0.6126, 0.0000],
         [0.8477, 0.1254, 0.4123, 0.5445, 0.7399, 0.0632, 0.5854, 0.5509]],

        [[0.4381, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0648, 0.3631, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.8157, 0.9059, 0.5619, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.0435, 0.0512, 0.3363, 0.6184, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3745, 0.8876, 0.7715, 0.8030, 0.4095, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.9497, 0.7047, 0.7892, 0.3666, 0.7344, 0.8568, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3247, 0.4709, 0.6927, 0.5807, 0.1428, 0.1495, 0.0891, 0.0000],
         [0.2706, 0.2700, 0.4818, 0.3050, 0.7016, 0.1638, 0.9822, 0.4592]],

        [[0.7152, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3284, 0.8040, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.3383, 0.1180, 0.6223, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.6223, 0.7493, 0.6532, 0.3418, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.8178, 0.3098, 0.9780, 0.4278, 0.3545, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.2103, 0.8859, 0.2867, 0.3903, 0.1155, 0.3743, 0.0000, 0.0000],
         [0.2489, 0.8765, 0.9539, 0.9262, 0.9264, 0.2574, 0.1568, 0.0000],
         [0.8775, 0.2113, 0.6749, 0.2828, 0.0220, 0.7423, 0.4340, 0.7593]]])
```

I don't know how to do this in LibTorch. There is [a page about slicing, indexing, and setting tensors for Libtorch here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_indexing.html), but it is kind of sparse. I don't see an translation of `:,` in Python in LibTorch here.

```
auto cholesky = torch::zeros({8, 8, 8});
auto cholesky_vector = torch::rand({8, 36});
auto trl = torch::tril_indices(8, 8, 0);

cholesky.index_put_({trl[0], trl[1]}, cholesky_vector);

std::cout << cholesky;
```

In Libtorch this returns an error because it wants `cholesky_vector` to be 36x8 for some reason, instead of 8x36. When I reverse it to 36x8 it does not return the desired values in the desired positions. It stores some values, but I don't know which ones, where, or why.